# exclusive arc in tsql - constraint to check one of the columns is not null

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am implementing exclusive arc pattern of resolving multiple parents for a given table. I wrote the below table level check constraint for use in SQL Server 2008. The proble with this, if there are 3 columns, the query grows so much bigger. Is there any better to do it?

```
check( 
(Parent1Id is null AND Parent2Id is not null) 
OR  (Parent1Id is not null AND Parent2Id is null))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `check(COALESCE(Parent1ID, Parent2ID) IS NOT NULL)` - this makes sure at least one is set, but to do the negative check I can't think of a quick solution.

Come to think of it, how about: (warning - not much shorter)

```
check(
CASE WHEN Parent1ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
+ CASE WHEN Parent2ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
+ CASE WHEN Parent3ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
+ CASE WHEN Parent4ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
= 1
)
```

Comment: @CK, Thanks. Yes the alternative you proposed is longer.

Comment: @CK, thanks for the coalesce function. What if I add another check constraint which checks for all the values NOT (A is not null AND B is not null). Can you put a NOT in the check constraint? Also, this query will also become a complex if 3 columns are involved.

Comment: The alternative is longer than the code you have, but for anything more than 2 values, it will be shorter (i.e. 3 lines for mine, 3 using your approach [but your lines will be longer, 4 lines for mine, 4 very long lines for yours])

Comment: Your NOT won't work as there will be multiple combinations for 3 or more columns.  I suggest you try your approach for 3 or more columns, then look at my second answer again.